# CSS repeat-y limit or alternative

Tags: html, css, blogger, background-repeat

I am building my first blog template and am trying to repeat the blog post background. I do NOT want the blog post background reaching to the top. Is there a way to do it without using the repeat-y command or a way to set limitations and parameters to repeat-y?

I have included a link to my blog as it currently stands. If you look at the blog, I am trying to make it so that the only background for the header is the page background, NOT the white post background. Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help! :)

Link to blog: http://shoelacesand.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have it about right as far as I can tell just remove your margin between blog post Div(fauxborder-left content-fauxborder-left) and the Header Section.

Edit:

Infact if you add

```
height: 400px
```

to this element **.header-inner .section**

It will line up how you want. However I would strongly advise reading a bit about responsive design before getting too involved with your work. As your site currently stand it breaks quite a lot of basic semantic and seo rules and does not resize in any way. I personally use a css framework as my base now. I spent weeks designing my last 3 draft layouts for my website before discovering Foundation Zurb, I'll never look back now. I would still advise learning Css well before relying on a Framework but once you have a grasp of it I'm sure you will find it is a life saver. Be sure to find the right framework for you before sticking to one though. A quick Google will find many comparison's of the options out there.